# Ignoring specific letters to find match in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query a table for all the values that are on a list on another table to find matches, but I know that some of the values in either table may be typed in incorrectly. One table may have '10Hf7K8' and another table may have '1OHf7K8' but I still want them to match.

Another example, if one table has 'STOP' but I know that in myTable, some of fields may say '5T0P' or 'ST0P' or '5TOP'. I want those to come up as results too. The same thing may occur for '2' and 'Z' if I want 'ZEPT' and '2EPT' to match.

So if I know to account for inconsistencies between '0' and 'O', '5' and 'S' and 'Z' and '2', and knowing that they will be in the same spot, but I do not know where exactly they will be in the word or how many letters the word will have, is it possible to make a query ignoring those letters?

Additional Information:  These values are hundreds of serial keys that I have no way of confirming which is correct version between the two tables. I should not have used actual words for my example, these values can be any combination of letters and numbers in any order. There is no distinct pattern that I can hard code.

SOLUTION: Goat CO, Learning, and user3216429's answers contained the solution I needed. I was able to find matching values while keeping the underlying data.

Comment: Is this in mySQL or SQL Server? Both are tagged.  Does one of the tables have only clean wordes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what form of data entry does your application have where this would be a problem? Can you edit the data entry form to prohibit the use of numeric characters?

Comment: @BobbyScon I was guessing it's an OCR fed input, but also curious.

Comment: what you can and should do is to clean your data, replace all these 2,0,5 with Z,O and S.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it mattered if it is in MySQL or SQL Server so I tagged both. No, both tables can either have '0' or 'O', there is no 'correct data'. This data is serial keys that are alphanumeric so there is no defined 'clean words' or 'correct words'. The data comes in the way the character is picked up by a scanner or when someone reads it, correctly or incorrectly.

Comment: Syntax and available functions vary by database.

Comment: No, ***pick a platform***. The solution may very well be different for one platform than the other, and it isn't fair to create a question where one person could answer for MySQL, and another could answer for SQL Server. If both create perfectly valid answers that work on their platform but not on the other, which answer would you select?

Comment: Thanks Learning, that is a good idea! That would require creating two separate table to store this temporary data. I will use this idea if no other solutions come up.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning data is preferable, but could use nested `REPLACE()` statements if you can't alter the underlying data:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table2 b
  ON REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(a.field1,'2','Z'),'5','S'),'0','O') = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(b.field1,'2','Z'),'5','S'),'0','O')
```

Cleansing the data could be the same nested replace statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD cleanfield VARCHAR(25)
UPDATE Table1
SET cleanfield = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dirtyfield,'2','Z'),'5','S'),'0','O')
```

Then you'd be able to join the tables on the clean field.

Comment: Thank you. This will query not alter the base tables in any way, correct?

Comment: @user3137500 the top query is just joining the two together making no changes to the underlying data, the bottom query would be an update on the table assuming you had already added a new empty field.

Comment: It could be wise to alter the base tables, by the way. Joining on the REPLACE function wouldn't use any indexes, and could obviously therefore be slow. If you were to create an *extra* column in each table, say `normalised_data` and run the same REPLACEs on each of your data columns into that column, then create an index on `normalised_data` you'd still keep your original data, but a join between the two `normalised_data` columns would be quick.

Comment: I'm using the top query. Thanks again! And thanks for the tip @Matt Gibson.

Answer (score 0):

what you can and should do is to clean your data, replace all these `2,0,5` with `Z,O and S`.

But if you want to try some other solution, then you can try something like this

```
select case when 
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('stop','0','o'),'5','s'),'2','Z') = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('5t0p','0','o'),'5','s'),'2','Z') then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Like previously said, if you have time, clean up the data.

If not,  SQL SERVER supplies two string functions that might help.

The example is from my blog article.  http://craftydba.com/?p=5211

The SOUNDEX() function turns a word into a 4 character value.  The DIFFERENCE() function tells you how close two words are.

Your example seems to be one word.  You might want to use a calculated column and index it so that the where clause is SARGABLE.

If you are using paragraphs, use a standard split function to turn your text paragraph into words.  Use these functions to search the data.  However, this will result in a non-SARGABLE expression.

```
-- Example returns 4, words are very close
select 
    soundex('Dog') as word_val1, 
    soundex('Dogs') as word_val2, 
    difference('Dog', 'Dogs') as how_close


-- Example returns 0, words are very different
select 
    soundex('Rattle-Snake') as word_val1, 
    soundex('Mongoose') as word_val2, 
    difference('Rattle-Snake', 'Mongoose') as how_close

output: 

word_val1 word_val2 how_close
--------- --------- -----------
D200      D200      4


word_val1 word_val2 how_close
--------- --------- -----------
R340      M522      0
```

Last but not least, you an also look into FULL text indexing for speed.  This requires some extra overhead (FTI structure and process to update FTI).

http://craftydba.com/?p=1421

Answer (score 0):

```
  select REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE([column_name],'O','0'),'Z','2'),'5','S')
  from [table_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) To filter out all rows containing all forms of STOP word (STOP, 5TOP, ST0P, 5T0P) you could use following query based on LIKE:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT 1, 'CocoJambo' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, '5T0P' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, ' 5TOP ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, '  ST0P ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, '   STOP ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'ZTOP'
) x (ID, ColA)
WHERE x.ColA LIKE '%[5S]T[0O]P%';
```

Output:

```
ID          ColA
----------- ---------
2           5T0P
3            5TOP 
4             ST0P 
5              STOP
```

2) Regarding your question:

For every table

- first I would try to build a table with all patterns for every word and for every pattern I would store the proper/accurate word,
- then I would try to replace every occurrence of  pattern with the proper word

After this *prepossessing* of these two tables I will try to match both tables.

This script will replace only **the first** occurrence of pattern

```
SELECT x.*, oa.*, 
    CASE 
        WHEN oa.PatIx > 0 THEN STUFF( x.ColA , oa.PatIx , LEN(oa.Word), oa.Word )
        ELSE x.ColA
    END AS NewColA
FROM (
    SELECT 1, 'CocoJambo' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, '5T0P' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, ' 5TOP ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, '  ST0P ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, '   STOP jambo jumbo 5TOP bOb ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, 'ZTOP'
) x (ID, ColA)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  *
    FROM (
        SELECT  w.WordPattern, w.Word, PATINDEX( w.WordPattern , x.ColA ) AS PatIx
        FROM    @Words w 
    ) y
    WHERE y.PatIx > 0
) oa
```

Output:

```
ID ColA                          WordPattern  Word PatIx NewColA
-- ----------------------------- ------------ ---- ----- ----------------------------
1  CocoJambo                     %b[o0]%      bob  8     CocoJambob
2  5T0P                          %[5S]T[0O]P% STOP 1     STOP
3   5TOP                         %[5S]T[0O]P% STOP 2      STOP 
4    ST0P                        %[5S]T[0O]P% STOP 3       STOP 
5     STOP jambo jumbo 5TOP bOb  %[5S]T[0O]P% STOP 4        STOP jambo jumbo 5TOP bOb
5     STOP jambo jumbo 5TOP bOb  %b[o0]%      bob  12       STOP jambobjumbo 5TOP bOb
6  ZTOP                          NULL         NULL NULL  ZTOP
```

Note: this solution it's just a proof of concept. It needs development.

Or you could try this solution which replaces all wrong words with the proper form:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Words ( Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, WordSource NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, Word NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL );
INSERT dbo.Words ( WordSource , Word ) VALUES ( N'5T0P' , N'STOP' );
INSERT dbo.Words ( WordSource , Word ) VALUES ( N'5TOP' , N'STOP' );
INSERT dbo.Words ( WordSource , Word ) VALUES ( N'ST0P' , N'STOP' );
INSERT dbo.Words ( WordSource , Word ) VALUES ( N'b0b' , N'bob' );
INSERT dbo.Words ( WordSource , Word ) VALUES ( N'bOb' , N'bob' );
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReplaceWords (@ColA NVARCHAR(4000), @Num INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH CteRecursive 
AS 
(
    SELECT  w.Id, w.WordSource, w.Word, REPLACE(@ColA, w.WordSource, w.Word) AS NewColA
    FROM    dbo.Words w
    WHERE   w.Id = 1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT  w.Id, w.WordSource, w.Word, REPLACE(prev.NewColA, w.WordSource, w.Word) AS NewColA
    FROM    CteRecursive prev INNER JOIN dbo.Words w ON prev.Id + 1 = w.Id  
    WHERE   prev.Id + 1 <= @Num
)
SELECT  r.NewColA
FROM    CteRecursive r
WHERE   r.Id = @Num
GO

-- Testing 
SELECT * FROM dbo.ReplaceWords(N'   ST0P jambo 5TOP bOb jumbo ', 5) f;
```

Output

```
NewColA
----------------------------
   STOP jambo STOP bob jumbo
```

You can use previous function to replace all wrong words within every table and then you can compare both tables:

```
DECLARE @Num INT;
SET @Num = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  dbo.Words);

SELECT x.*, rpl.NewColA
FROM (
    SELECT 1, N'CocoJambo' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, N'5T0P' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, N' 5TOP ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4, N'  ST0P ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5, N'   STOP jambo jumbo 5TOP bOb ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6, N'ZTOP' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7, N'' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8, NULL
) x (ID, ColA)
OUTER APPLY dbo.ReplaceWords(x.ColA, @Num) rpl
```

Output:

```
ID ColA                          NewColA
-- ----------------------------- ----------------------------
1  CocoJambo                     CocoJambo
2  5T0P                          STOP
3   5TOP                          STOP 
4    ST0P                          STOP 
5     STOP jambo jumbo 5TOP bOb     STOP jambo jumbo STOP bob
6  ZTOP                          ZTOP
7                                
8  NULL                          NULL
```